# How to use a protocol with optional class methods in an extension with generic in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I am trying using extension for an existing class with class method like:

```
@objc public protocol MyProtocol {
    optional class func foo() -> Int
}
```

And I am using this protocol in an extension with generic like:

```
extension MyClass {

    public func bar<T: MyProtocol>() {
        ...
        let x: Int = T.self.foo!() // if I do not use "self" or "!" here, I will have a compiler error
        ...
    }
```

This should work but when I build it, Xcode says "Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1". If I do not use "optional" in the protocol, I do not need to unwrap the foo() in the extension and everything works well even if I remove the "self". Can anyone tell me why and how to make the optional work properly?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've found a (fairly obscure) bug in the Swift compiler that's causing it to crash.
  Here's a reproduction that's all you need in a single file to crash `swiftc`:

```
import Foundation
@objc protocol P { optional class func f() }
func f<T: P>(t: T) { T.self.f?() }
```

(you don't need to call `f` for it to crash)

You should probably file a radar since the compiler crashing is never expected behavior no matter  what your code.

If you tried to do this without the `optional`, it'll work (and you can even ditch the `self`).  My guess is the implementation of generics doesn't currently account for the possibility of optional class-level functions.

You can do it without generics like this:

```
func f(p: MyProtocol) {
    (p as AnyObject).dynamicType.foo?()
}
```

(there may even be a better way but I can't spot it).

You need the `AnyObject` cast because if you try to call `.dynamicType.foo?()` on `p` directly you get "accessing members of protocol type value 'MyProtocol.Type' is unimplemented".  I wouldn't be surprised if the crash of the generic version is related to this.

I'd also say that its worth asking yourself whether you really need a protocol with optional methods (especially class-level ones) and whether there's a way to do what you want entirely statically using generics (as you're already semi-doing).

Comment: The practical code about this is much more complicated. It is how I optimize the design of using Alamofire with router. It is ok not to use optional (just a couple of extra lines), but the problem really confused me. Thank you for the explanation!